# How to set Property for all fields from a pdf document

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, field

I have many fields in a pdf document and I want to set a property for all of them.

example:

`fields.SetFieldProperty("nr1", "textfont", baseFont, null);`
`fields.SetFieldProperty("nr2", "textfont", baseFont, null);`
`fields.SetFieldProperty("nr3", "textfont", baseFont, null);`
`fields.SetFieldProperty("nr4", "textfont", baseFont, null);`
`fields.SetFieldProperty("nr5", "textfont", baseFont, null);`

Is there any method to set all fields at once with the same property?
I want to avoid setting each field separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like that, maybe (untested)

```
var baseFont = new Font();
var reader = new PdfReader(@"test");
var fields = reader.AcroFields;
foreach (var f in fields.Fields.Select(x => x.Key))
      fields.SetFieldProperty(f, "textfont", baseFont, null);
```

or as I don't know much about your code...

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   fields.SetFieldProperty(string.Format("nr{0}", i), "textfont", baseFont, null);
```